# Configure Apache Ant and Ivy on Windows 7

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I'm been attempting to clone and build a project on my Windows 7 box, like so:

```
git clone git@github.com:corvec/project-name.git
cd project-name
git submodule init
git submodule update
ant clean
ant resolve
```

All of the commands up until `ant resolve` work as expected, which gives me the following error message:

```
Buildfile: c:\workspace\project-name\build.xml

clean-lib:
   [delete] Deleting directory c:\workspace\project-name\lib

load-ivy:

resolve:
     [echo] Storing dependencies in lib dir: lib
    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\workspace\project-name\lib
[ivy:retrieve] :: Ivy 2.1.0 - 20090925235825 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:retrieve] :: loading settings :: file = c:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\ivy\ivysettings.xml

BUILD FAILED
c:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ivy-targets.xml:55: impossible to configure
ivy:settings with given file: c:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\ivy\ivysettings.xml
: java.text.ParseException: failed to load settings from file:/c:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/ivy/ivysettings.xml: io problem while parsing config file: unknown protocol: c
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:165)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.parse(XmlSettingsParser.java:150)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.IvySettings.load(IvySettings.java:384)
        at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.configure(Ivy.java:411)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyAntSettings.createIvyEngine(IvyAntSettings.java:272)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyAntSettings.getConfiguredIvyInstance(IvyAntSettings.java:237)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.getIvyInstance(IvyTask.java:92)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.prepareTask(IvyTask.java:256)
        at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:276)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.startElement(XmlSettingsParser.java:234)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:179)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:277)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.doParse(XmlSettingsParser.java:160)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.includeStarted(XmlSettingsParser.java:409)
        at org.apache.ivy.core.settings.XmlSettingsParser.startElement(XmlSettingsParser.java:211)
        ... 38 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

EDIT: With the verbose flag applied, I now get the following message:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.0 compiled on March 5 2013
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre
Detected OS: Windows 7
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/build.xml
Project base dir set to: C:\workspace\project-name
parsing buildfile jar:file:/c:/apache-ant-1.9.0/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/c:/apache-ant-1.9.0/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading C:\workspace\project-name\build.properties
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/build-basic-targets.xml
Already defined in main or a previous import, ignore build-tests
Already defined in main or a previous import, ignore dist-war
Already defined in main or a previous import, ignore all
Already defined in main or a previous import, ignore console
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ant-contrib-targets.xml from
C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ant-contrib-targets.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/build-ant-contrib-targets.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ivy-targets.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ivy-targets.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/build-ivy-targets.xml
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ant-contrib-targets.xml from
C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ivy-targets.xml
Skipped already imported file:
   C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ant-contrib-targets.xml

Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ivy-targets.xml
Skipped already imported file:
   C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml

 [property] Loading C:\workspace\project-name\placeholder.build.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: C:\workspace\project-name\placeholder.build.properties
 [property] Loading C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\ivy\ivysettings.properties
Property "ivy.basedir" has not been set
Property "ivy.basedir" has not been set
Override ignored for property "shared.base"
Override ignored for property "shared.lib"
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
 [property] Loading C:\workspace\project-name\placeholder.build.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: C:\workspace\project-name\placeholder.build.properties
Override ignored for property "conf.web.dir"
Override ignored for property "jdk.lib"
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-testing-targets.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-testing-targets.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/build-testing-targets.xml
 [macrodef] creating macro  do-testing
 [macrodef] creating macro  test-one-class
 [macrodef] creating macro  test-classes
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-eclipse-classpath.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-eclipse-classpath.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/build-eclipse-classpath.xml
 [property] Loading C:\workspace\project-name\placeholder.build.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: C:\workspace\project-name\placeholder.build.properties
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-findBugs-targets.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-findBugs-targets.xml with
URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/build-findBugs-targets.xml
Override ignored for property "shared.lib"
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-pmd-targets.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-pmd-targets.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/core-build/xml/ant/build-pmd-targets.xml
Override ignored for property "shared.lib"
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Overriding previous definition of reference to lib.jars
Build sequence for target(s) `resolve' is [clean-lib, load-ivy, resolve]
Complete build sequence is [clean-lib, load-ivy, resolve, build, build-tests, -missing-test-param, project-name.run-one-test-plain, project-name.run-tests-xml, project-name.clean, check-findbugs-filters, runFindBugsFiltered, runFindBugsUnfiltered, project-name.runFindBugs, eclipse-classpath, dist, dist-war, project-name.run-one-test-html, pmd.pmd-html, report, runFindBugsFiltered-html, runFindBugsUnfiltered-html, runFindBugs-html, project-name.dist, project-name.dist-onejar, project-name.eclipse-classpath-with-conf, project-name.clean-cache, instrument-classes, run-tests, report-tests, report-coverage, ivy-version, publish-nodeps,
publish, project-name.publish-nodeps, project-name.run-tests, cpd, run-tests-html, cpd-html, pmd, pmd-all, project-name.ivy-local-version, project-name.create-javadoc, run-one-test-html, project-name.publish, project-name.runFindBugsFiltered-html, resolve-all, run-master-testsuites, clean-local, pmd-html, pmd.pmd-all-html, ivy-local-version, project-name.clean-all-local, runFindBugs, console, pmd.pmd-all, run-one-test-plain, clean-all-local, project-name.resolve_delivered, project-name.report, project-name.load-ivy, project-name.runFindBugs-html, project-name.clean-lib, project-name.post-resolve-echo, project-name.dist-war, project-name.ivy-version, pmd.cpd-html, project-name.ivy-new-version, dist-jar, ivy-new-version, resolve_delivered, project-name.runFindBugsFiltered, project-name.copy-dependencies, project-name.publish-local-nodeps, post-resolve-echo, dist-onejar, clean-cache, project-name.run-tests-plain, create-javadoc, project-name.build, run-test, project-name.all, run-tests-plain, pmd.cpd, test, copy-dependencies, publish-local-nodeps, publish-local, project-name.pom, project-name.report-coverage-xml, report-coverage-xml, project-name.console, project-name.report-tests, project-name.test, project-name.instrument-classes, pmd.pmd, clean, project-name.publish-local, copy-dist, run-jar, dist-reports, project-name.build-tests, project-name.copy-dist, project-name.run-one-test, project-name.dist-reports, project-name.check-findbugs-filters, project-name.-missing-test-param, run-one-test-xml, run-one-test, report-master-testsuites,
project-name.runFindBugsUnfiltered-html, project-name.resolve, build-dep, project-name.dist-jar, project-name.runFindBugsUnfiltered, all, project-name.report-master-testsuites, project-name.build-dep, project-name.resolve-all, project-name.clean-local, pom, project-name.run-tests-html, eclipse-classpath-with-conf, project-name.run-master-testsuites, run-tests-xml, project-name.eclipse-classpath, project-name.run-test, project-name.run-jar, pmd-all-html, project-name.report-coverage, project-name.run-one-test-xml, ]

clean-lib:

load-ivy:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
[antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-ivy-targets.xml:24: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration.
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -c:\apache-ant-1.9.0\lib
        -C:\Users\localuser\.ant\lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument

        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:487)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:419)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

I doubt this is an issue with the configuration specific to the project; I'm not the only developer on this project and the other developers have it working. More likely, it is something related to my system's configuration. They are running Linux and Mac OS, if that makes a difference. I suppose it could potentially be related to some files that are not being tracked by git, but I would think that one of the other developers would have noticed that.

I *have* tried updating the file paths in `build.properties` to use an absolute path rather than a relative one, as follows (based on [this recommendation](http://grokbase.com/t/ant/ivy-user/0888b7bs6k/newbie-cant-configure-ivy-from-local-file-in-windows)):

```
shared.base=file:///c:/workspace/project-name/core-build
```

instead of

```
shared.base=core-build
```

When I do that, I get the following error message:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.0 compiled on March 5 2013
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre
Detected OS: Windows 7
parsing buildfile C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/workspace/project-name/build.xml
Project base dir set to: C:\workspace\project-name
parsing buildfile jar:file:/c:/apache-ant-1.9.0/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/c:/apache-ant-1.9.0/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading C:\workspace\project-name\build.properties
Importing file C:\workspace\project-name\file:\C:\workspace\project-name\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml from C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml:5: Cannot find C:\workspace\project-name\file:\C:\workspace\project-name\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml imported from C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.importResource(ImportTask.java:181)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ImportTask.execute(ImportTask.java:162)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:179)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:82)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:826)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

To that end, here are some relevant details from my system:

```
PATH = %AMDAPPSDKROOT%bin\x86_64;%AMDAPPSDKROOT%bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%MAVEN%;%SBT_HOME%;%IRONRUBY_11%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin;%SUBVERSION%\bin;%GIT%\cmd;C:\Utilities;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;%ANT_HOME%\bin
echo %PATH% = c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\;C:\Program Files (x86)\IronRuby 1.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin;C:\Grails\grails-2.1.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-2.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Utilities;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\apache-ant-1.9.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim73;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Python27
%ANT_HOME% = C:\apache-ant-1.9.0
%JAVA_HOME% = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
javac -version = 1.6.0_25
```

I have also attempted to use a new version of Ivy, ivy-2.3.0, but I encounter similar errors.

I think this section is the ivy resolve target:

```
<target name="resolve" depends="clean-lib, load-ivy" description="--> resolve and retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <echo message="Storing dependencies in lib dir: ${lib.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="lib"/>
    <ivy:retrieve />

    <ivy:deliver deliverpattern="ivy_delivered.xml" />
</target>
```

**Paths**

I've included relevant excerpts of the paths in the build.properties and other related files below:

```
// build.xml
<property file="build.properties" />
// build.properties
shared.base=core-build
shared.xml=${shared.base}/xml
// build-ivy-targets.xml (imported into build.xml)
<property name="ivy.settings.dir" value="${shared.xml}/ant/ivy" />
```

**Ivy Configuration**

```
<!-- build-ivy-targets.xml (stripped down quite a bit): -->
<project basedir="." default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
    <import file="build-ant-contrib-targets.xml" />
    <import file="build-basic-targets.xml" />

    <property file="placeholder.build.properties" />
    <property name="ivy.settings.dir" value="${shared.xml}/ant/ivy" />
    <property file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.properties" />

    <path id="ivy.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${shared.lib}">
            <include name="ant-extensions/ivy*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="lib.jars">
        <fileset id="lib.jars.fileset" dir="lib" erroronmissingdir="false">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- `ivy:settings file` is only set here: -->
    <target name="load-ivy">
        <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path" />
        <ivy:settings file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml" />
    </target>
    <target name="resolve" depends="clean-lib, load-ivy" description="--> resolve and retrieve dependencies with ivy">
        <echo message="Storing dependencies in lib dir: ${lib.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="lib"/>
        <ivy:retrieve />

        <ivy:deliver deliverpattern="ivy_delivered.xml" />
    </target>
    <target name="clean-lib" description="--> clean the project libraries directory (dependencies)">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" dir="${lib.dir}" />
    </target>

</project>
```

I've figured out that the Apache Ivy error message means that somewhere it is failing to parse a directory and is instead reading it as a URL. What steps should I take to fix this?

Comment: You have specified the error messages but you haven't listed the ANT code. I suspect the problem is that you have specified the namespace for the settings task. FOr example "ivy:settings"

Comment: Can you paste `resolve` target? I think that your installation of ivy is incomplete or yo're passing wrong path to `ivysettings.xml`. Maybe this path is hardcoded?

Comment: @pepuch - What do you mean by the `resolve` target? Is that the file starting with `<project basedir="." default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">`? Or is it just the section starting with ` <target name="resolve" depends="clean-lib, load-ivy" description="--> resolve and retrieve dependencies with ivy">`? I'll paste the latter into my question.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, which ANT code are you referencing? The build.xml file? The build.xml file references a LOT of other files. The only place that I see `ivy:settings` is under the `load-ivy` target. I'll paste that excerpt into my answer as well.

Comment: failed to load settings from file:/c:/w .. Is this missing one /.  file://c:

Comment: @Jayan, the error message had only one `/` after `file:`. However, all of the paths in the config files were relative, so that incorrect format was somehow completely generated by ivy and ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivy on Windows needs the ivy-settings variable to be set differently than on Linux.

Change the line `<ivy:settings file="${ivy.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml" />` to:

```
<ivy:settings url="file:/C://workspace//project-name//core-build//xml//ant//ivy//ivysettings.xml" />
```

It's important to note that two things change:

1. Rather than setting `ivy.settings.file`, you are setting `ivy.settings.url`
2. You are setting an absolute path rather than a relative one.

Comment: I'm going to avoid accepting this for at least the rest of today, in case someone that understands *why* ivy does this wants to expound upon it in an answer. I'd rather accept that sort of answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ant is trying to resolve an import from a relative path rather than an absolute location.  See this line in your error?

> Cannot find C:\workspace\project-name\file:\C:\workspace\project-name\project-name\core-build\xml\ant\build-basic-targets.xml imported from C:\workspace\project-name\build.xml

Make the path to the imported file be a path relative to the build.xml's directory, like "project-name/core-build/xml/ant/basic-build-targets.xml", and your import statement look something like this:

```
<import file="${basedir}/${shared.base}"/>
```

Comment: I only saw that error message when I changed the path specifically to be absolute. The other error messages were all received with a path relative to both `build.xml` and the current working directory when executing the `ant` command.